# Why do you have declare/create a separate variable to call by reference rather than just creating an automatic object in the function call?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

given:

```
void foo(std::string &s) { 
 ...
}
```

Why does this result in a compiler error:

```
foo(std::string("fail"));
```

where as this is fine:

```
std::string s("winning");
foo(s);
```

the error for the failure case is
`error: no matching function for call to ‘foo(std::string)’`

in the winning case, I thought the compiler would just optimize out `s` anyway.  What concept am I missing here?

Comment: What do you gain from modifying the temporary string?

Comment: I'm not modifying it.  Maybe foo(string) is calling somehashmap.find(string).

Comment: @marathon then it should be const.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pass by non-`const` reference is used for output (and inout) parameters.

When you pass a temporary, there's no place for the output to go and be retrieved by the caller.  So the language rules don't permit that.  (With one exception -- `this` can bind to a temporary even in non-`const` member functions)

If the parameter is input-only, pass by `const` reference.  If the parameter transfers ownership to the function, pass by rvalue reference.  Both of these accept temporaries.

Answer (score 1):

As said, your function are asking for a modifiable string and you are giving a const (all temps are const). Modify your function signature to that:

```
void foo(const std::string &s) { 
 ...
}
```

With a const reference parameter and all will work as you expect.